# Read html from temporary folder

Tags: browser

After typing any URL in the browser, the HTML source code of that page is downloaded on our local machine's temporary folder. Browser is displayed that page from temporary folder.

Is any way to access those URL from temporary folder while internet is disconnected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried enabling "Offline Mode" or similar in your browser's menus (usually File)?